# Real Analysis: Taylor Polynomial

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ has three derivatives and that the third Taylor Polynomial at $x=0$ is $p_3(x)=1+4x-x^2+x^3/6$. Show that there is a neighborhood of the point 0 such that $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is positive, strictly increasing, and has a strictly decreasing derivative.

I can "see" why it is strictly increasing, the help I need is "proving" it is strictly increasing.

This is homework! I welcome any hints to get me going, thanks!

Comment: Well, what is the derivative of $f$ at 0? And what about its second derivative?

Comment: wouldn't it be 4 for the first and -2 for the second?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Should it read 'strictly decreasing derivative'?

Comment: ah yes, I had to google typos for the book I am using and you are right, it should say "strictly decreasing derivative." No wonder I was confused. I will fix that right now!

Comment: My lightbulb went off, thanks for the help everyone!